# How can I automate a slider using watir-webdriver and ruby?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to automate a Jquery UI slider using watir-webdriver and ruby but am having no luck. I want to be able to manipulate the slider to either increase or decrease the value. I have searched everywhere and asked a few of my colleagues but no one has an answer. I am attaching a piece of HTML code for the slider. Any help would be much appreciated.

URL link: http://www.whatcar.com/new-car-deals/ (price range slider)

I haven't done any coding for the slider as I have no idea how to go about it. If I could be set on the right path that would be fantastic. Also it seems the HTML code doesn't seem to be showing on the question I am asking.

Comment: A link to a demo page and what you've tried already would make it easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link.. that makes it much easier.   When working with that page, be sure to read their terms and ensure that what you are doing with it does not violate their terms of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a Jquery widget that appears (looking at the scripts) to respond to key presses once one of the handles has been clicked on.  the handles are link objects, inside a pair of divs, the outer one has the ID value 'slider-range'

You should be able to address them via `browser.div(:id => 'slider-range').link(:index => n)` where n = 0 for the lefthand one and n=1 for the right hand one.

Try this manually first

- Click on the left handle for the slider
- Then press arrow keys on the keyboard..  it will move 1K(pounds) up or down with each right or left arrow keypress.
- Once you have moved it right, click the Home key and it should reset to its min value
- repeat above for the right handle but reset it to far right using the End key.

In theory you could fire a click event at the right slider to get focus, then fire off some keypress events to first set it far right (end) followed by enough left arrows to move it down to the top value you want.

Repeat for the left handle, setting it to the left end with the home key, and moving it with right arrow keypresses

I don't have the time right now to experiment further and develop an exact script, but I think you could probably create two little functions even that took an upper and lower range value and did the required number of keypresses to move the lower up from 5K to the right amount, and the upper down from 100k

Note that this thing is very very event driven, it responds (at least when watching the dev tools while playing with it) to being moused over, mousedown, mouseup, etc..  if using click does not work to 'get the attention' of the control so it will respond to keypresses, try using the onmousedown event instead.

Using the code from your answer, to move the left slider to 12K I'd try

```
browser.div(:id => 'slider-range').link(:index => 0).click  #make sure it has focus
browser.div(:id => 'slider-range').link(:index => 0).send_keys :home #set to 5K    
7.times do
   browser.div(:id => 'slider-range').link(:index => 0).send_keys :arrow_right
end
```

Comment: Thanks will give that a go tomorrow morning. If successful will post the solution, otherwise will let you know what I have done. Once again many thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Chuck. I got it working. Here is the script I used:

```
@browser.link(:xpath, "/html/body/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/a").send_keys :arrow_right
```

Still needs a bit of tweaking, but I should be ok now.

Comment: Why the xpath?  it just makes it impossbile to see what your code is doing, and also makes it very brittle, changes to the layout of the page are going to make that break all the time.  xpath is horrid stuff, only use it if nothing else works.  On the page you gave there's a handy ID value for the div that holds the stuff that does the slider range, and it looks pretty static (more static than the nesting of the divs on the page.  Why not use `browser.div(:id => 'slider-range').link(:index => 1).send_keys :arrow_right' instead?

Comment: are you a reforming Selenium user? (just curious) it seems like people who are used to Selenium get addicted to selecting stuff via these hidious xpath expressions that are brittle as hell and hard to read.  I mean seriously two months from now, will you have ANY clue what element is being interacted with there?  and how long will it take you to trace it down via the DOM.. compare that to using the Watir api properly, where you can immediately identify which div holds the control you are sending keys to..

Comment: I'm a Watir user and have never really used Selenium to the level I use watir-webdriver. I totally understand where your coming from. I always do my coding by showing the actual elements. Just used xpath for this particular example. (Won't make same mistake again). Anyway once again thank you very much for the feedback and I have taken aboard the advice that you have passed on. Will try to stay away from xpath

Comment: There are sometimes when it's the only practical way to identify something, but most times, there are better alternatives.  Have fun using Watir!

Answer (score 0):

This worked great. We just added these sliders to our website and my first thought was "how are we going to automate that!?"

I wanted to add an example will full code that is available publicly for people to experiment with. The following interacts with an example on jqueryui.com.

```
require "watir-webdriver"
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
@browser.goto "http://jqueryui.com/slider/#default"
@browser.frame(:class => "demo-frame").span(:class =>"ui-slider-handle").click
@browser.frame(:class => "demo-frame").span(:class =>"ui-slider-handle").send_keys :home 
puts "clicked home"
7.times do
  @browser.frame(:class => "demo-frame").span(:class =>"ui-slider-handle").send_keys :arrow_right
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this using Rspec and Watir-Webdriver with Page-Object gem I used:

```
div(:slider, id: "slider-range") #in page file
#then in spec file
browser.slider_element.input.send_keys :home
```

This answer comes from http://watir.com/guides/special-keys/